# MVC redirect to error page doesn't display message

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In MVC I am trying to redirect a message to an Error page when it occurs. The Error Page will open but I get no error message.
This is the method that initiates the process.

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveSurvey(vmFollowUpSurvey model)
        { 
        var result = surveyBL.postSurveyResults(model);

        if (result != "Record Saved")
            {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Survey not saved");
            var redirectUrl = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Action("Index", "Error");
            return Json(new { Url = redirectUrl });
            }
        else
            {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Survey completed");
            var redirectUrl = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Action("Index", "Login");
            return Json(new { Url = redirectUrl });
            }

        }
```

My ErrorController then has a method of

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
        return View();
        }
```

And my View displays as this

```
<h2>Survey Information Page</h2>

<div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Error"))
{
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-info" })
    </div> 
</div>
}


</div>
```

So what did I not do to get this to display?

Comment: you are not returning error inside json ?

Comment: did you got idea or shall I help you to rewrite code .

Comment: not sure I understand I thought the Validationsummary would handle that

Comment: but where is your model ? on error controller and u r returining JsonResult . i dont see model

Comment: i can try to create a sample app please give me your source code of controler  and template

Comment: public class vmError
        {
        public string ErrorStatus { get; set; }
        }
    }

Comment: Just give me 5 min I will post my answer .

Comment: Please check I updated my answer hopefully this is what you asked for .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ErrorController.Index()` method has no knowledge of the model being used, so adding the message to `ModelState` will mean your error page doesn't have access to it. If you're going to be redirecting to a different view, the proper way to handle this would be to put the error inside the `Session`.

```
if (result != "Record Saved")
{
    Session["Error"] = "Survey not saved";
    ...
}
```

Then inside your Error view, you can do something like this:

```
<h2>Survey Information Page</h2>

<div>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Error"))
    {
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <span class="error-message">@Session["Error"]</span>
            </div> 
        </div>
    }

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
             [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveSurvey(vmFollowUpSurvey model)
        { 
        var result = surveyBL.postSurveyResults(model);

        if (result != "Record Saved")
            {        
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error", new  {  ErrorMessage=  "Survey not saved"} );
            }
        else
            {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Survey completed");
            var redirectUrl = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Action("Index", "Login");
            return Json(new { Url = redirectUrl });
            }

        }


        --- ErrorModel Class

        namespace WebApplication3.Models
    {
        public class ErrorModel
        {
            public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        }
    }

    --- Error Index.html code 

    @model WebApplication3.Models.ErrorModel
    <h2>Survey Information Page</h2>

    <div>

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Error"))
        {
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(false,  Model.ErrorMessage  , new { @class = "text-info" })
                </div>
            </div>
        }


    </div>
```